# Convexity of an inequality constraint

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis

According to some references, following inequality constraint in $w \in \mathbb C^2$ is not convex.
\begin{equation}
\frac{|c^H w|^2}{\|Aw\|_2^2+\|Bw\|_2^2} \geq r_k, \qquad (1) 
\end{equation}
where $A$ and $B$ are $2 \times 2$ matrices and $c$ is a $2$-vector

However, after some phase rotation, the absolute value of the complex number in the numerator can be written as

\begin{equation}
|c^H w| = \mathbb{R}\{e^{-j \theta} c^H w \}, \text{ where } \theta = \arg\{c^H w\}. \qquad (2)
\end{equation} 
Then, after some manipulation, eqn (1) can be expressed again in the form of 
\begin{equation}
\|\Phi w + d\| \leq \mathbb{R}\{e^{-j \theta} c^H w \} \qquad (3) 
\end{equation}
which becomes a convex constraint as a SOCP (second order cone programming) form.

Here, I am very wondering why eqn (1) is a non-convex constraint, and eqn (3) is a convex constraint (How can we prove their non-convexity and convexity of (1) and (3), respectively ?).

Comment: Is your question about what makes a constraint convex, or how to deal with complex numbers in constraints?

Comment: What vector norm are you using?

Comment: (To LarrySnyder610) The constraint  is a non-convex constraint. I am wondering why it is a non-convex, and what can make the constraint convex. \\                        (To Rodirigo de Azevedo) The vector norm is 2-norm.

Comment: For a fix $\theta$, (3) is indeed convex. However, if you don't know $\theta$ and it is arbitrary, (3) is non-convex.

Comment: $\theta$ is fixed. Why is (1) non-convex? How we could prove it?